# how to use OpenSmile in C# and MFCC Extraction

Tags: c#, dll, static-libraries, wav, mfcc

I wanna use OpenSmile library in C#
and extract MFCC feature of WAV files, 
but i don't know how can I use 'OpenSmile_Release.dll'
Is there any one can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I export main file as a function and create a native DLL.

then import it to C#.